# Setting Callback URL and retrieve data using RestSharp

Tags: c#, callback, restsharp

I am calling an Restful API that expects me to pass a parameter callback(a URL)when doing POST.
The tool that I am using to make the call is RESTSharp. I have written the below code

```
var client = new RestClient("https://services.mywebsite.com/api/v3/");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("Usernamae", "P2$$w0rd");

var request = new RestRequest("myAction", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

request.AddParameter("Id", "sid");
request.AddParameter("callback", "http://localhost"); // ????????
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddFile("file", @"e:\MyDocuemnt.pdf");

client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

The line with the parameter callback requires me to pass a url
what should I be passing in here ?
the result is passed back to the callback Url provided, how do I get to see that?

My application is a console application and I want to capture the result here.

Comment: You are trying to see the response that's sent to the callback URL, as opposed to the response for your RestRequest? Do you have an endpoint listening at that URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API is expecting a place to dump the results after it has been processed.

This is what is happening as per my understanding.

1. You make a call to the API and expects you to provide a callback url
2. The API returns you a response.

Now the question here is where is my result and if it is sent to the callback url how do I get it.

This is waht you need to do.

You could create a Web API with a POST method that would do the trick for you.
Make sure you are hosting your WebApi which should be accessible by the service which you are calling and expect to send you the result.

```
            public void Post([FromBody]JToken value)
            {
                var path = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");

                File.WriteAllText(path + @"/WriteJSON" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".txt", value.ToString());

                // write any code that you want to here

            }
```

This should do the trick for you.All i am doing here is writing the response back you may want to do whatever you wish to do with this.